# problem with a 2 dimensional array(list of list of dict)

Tags: python

```
cell={'num':0,'state':1}
cell_2d=[]
cell_list=[]
for i in range(2):
  for j in range(2):
    cell_list=cell_list+[cell]
  cell_2d=cell_2d+[cell_list]
  cell_list=[]
print "initially:"
print cell_2d
cell_2d[0][0]['num']=-1
print "finally:"
print cell_2d
```

Output obtained is:

initially:
[[{'state': 1, 'num': 0}, {'state': 1, 'num': 0}], [{'state': 1, 'num': 0}, {'state': 1, 'num': 0}]]
finally:
[[{'state': 1, 'num': -1}, {'state': 1, 'num': -1}], [{'state': 1, 'num': -1}, {'state': 1, 'num': -1}]]

when the line 11 is executed, I expect only the first element of the first list of cell_2d to be changed. But the output shows that all 'num' of all elements of cell_2d is changed to -1. Not able to get why this is happening. Can someone please tell me what is the mistake with the code? Thanx in advance.

Comment: Can you edit your answer, and use the 101010 button to mark code sections, so they're formatted as code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I see it. You're reusing the `cell` object. Because Python uses references, you're just making four references to the same object, so when you change one, you change them all.

Inside your inner loop, try:

```
cell_list = cell_list + [{'num':1, 'state':0}]
```

Which can be shortened to:

```
cell_list.append({'num':1, 'state':0})
```

Or, in fact, you can replace the inner loop (with j) with:

```
cell_list = [{'num':1, 'state':0} for j in range(2)]
```

Comment: @Newbie_python: this is more efficient, too. Always use `.append` for a single item and `.extend` or `+=` for joining two lists. Also as a matter of principle, if you ever are doing it, instead of doing `cell_list = cell_list + ...`, do `cell_list += ...`; it's neater and faster (in place rather than creating another new list).

Comment: apart from that it is also possible to do cell_list.append( dict(cell) ), which makes a new copy of cell. As the contents of cell consists of immutable types this is safe.

Comment: @chris and extraneon : thanx fr the suggestion :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply replace this line

```
cell_2d=cell_2d+[cell_list]
```

With this

```
cell_2d = cell_2d + [ cell_list.copy() ]
```

This way python will make a copy from the dictionary 'cell_list' instead of storing a reference.

Comment: cell_list is not a dictionary. its a list of dictionary. So copy() method doesn't work on cell_list